# troubles with vector being passed into a function with pointer parameters c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector

I'm doing excercises given by a tutorial and they want the parameters on the function to be a pointer? The syntax is a bit confusing with these concepts so any clarity who be nice. I'm familiar with how they work, so no trouble there.

Keeps have conversion problems 'cannot convert std::vector int to int*'

Please let me know what the problem is and what might be causing the confusion, thanks.

Here's the code:

```
void randArrayFill(int* theArray, int aSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++)
    {
        *(theArray + 1) = rand() % 101;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int vecSize;
    vector<int> simpleVec;
    cin >> vecSize;
    simpleVec.resize(vecSize);
    randArrayFill(simpleVec, vecSize);


    for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
    {
        cout << simpleVec[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: A vector and an array are two different things. The argument is `int* theArray`, a pointer which presumably points to the first element of an array; you can't pass a vector in its place. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to pass a vector as int* parameter, using the syntax &simpleVec[0], I do not recommend to do this in your case. Because, you are passing an internal buffer of the vector<> class, and it is not a good idea to change its content bypassing the class control. You should use this technique only for reading and not for writing operations. So I suggest you to change your code in one of the following solutions:

```
void randArrayFill(std::vector<int>& theArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < theArray.size(); i++)
    {
        theArray[i] = rand() % 101;
    }
}
```

In this way you can pass a reference to your vector and manage it inside your function without problems. Your main should be:

```
int main()
{
    int vecSize;
    vector<int> simpleVec;
    cin >> vecSize;
    simpleVec.resize(vecSize);
    randArrayFill(simpleVec);

    for (int i = 0; i < theArray.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << simpleVec[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

if you need to understand pointers and do not want change your function declaration you can change your main as follow:

```
int main()
{
    int vecSize;
    int *simpleVec;
    cin >> vecSize;

    simpleVec = new int[vecSize]; // allocate memory for your vector

    randArrayFill(simpleVec, vecSize);


    for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
    {
        cout << simpleVec[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] simpleVec; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to get into the internal buffer of the vector and pass a pointer to this entity.  To get to the internal buffer, pass the address of the first element of the vector.

```
  randArrayFill(&simpleVec[0], vecSize);
```

Since a vector's internal buffer is layed out in contiguous memory, you're good here.  Also note that the very same syntax would have worked if simpleVec were a regular array, so you really don't have to change code if for some reason you decide to use an array instead of a vector.

The caveat is that you must make sure that the vector isn't empty, as getting the address of element 0 leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the same thing in this way.

```
void randArrayFill(vector<int>& theArray, int aSize)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++)
   {
       theArray[i] = rand() % 101;
   }
   return ;
}

int main()
{
   int vecSize;
   vector<int> simpleVec;
   cin >> vecSize;
   simpleVec.resize(vecSize);
   randArrayFill(simpleVec, vecSize);
   for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
   {
       cout << simpleVec[i] << endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```